# Get user name from Azure authenticated AD in .Net Web API

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a web API that is authenticated by Azure's AD.
Within the API codes, what is the code to retrieve the username of the authenticated user?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place like _what is the code for..._. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Comment: Try System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: Always show the code you have written to community, otherwise it feels to us that you are using us to write your code, We like to see efforts before we help.

Answer (score 5):

Using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` will retrieve the email address that they have used to log in with.

As a side note, I am using this to control what the user has access to on the site. Because of how I am implementing it, it is more convenient for me to maintain a database of the usernames and their roles. However, if you are doing the same thing, it is also worth looking into `[Authorize]` and maintaining site access that way.